# Where can I help students for free in real-time? (not openstudy.com)

Tags: tutoring

I'm convinced that, at any given time, there are hundreds (perhaps thousands) of English-speaking students looking for real-time chat-based math help for free.

My question: how do I find them and help them for free?

More info: every so often, I get bored and feel like spending an hour or so helping people with math online. Sites like openstudy.com sort of allow me to do this, but don't have a good real-time chat interface, so communication is ugly.

openstudy.com also discourages people from giving students external links (eg, I can help you at my scribblar.com whiteboard at ... ).

Is there a good solution here?

Comment: Do you require real-time chat? Otherwise, good old math.stackexchange.com fits your needs.

Comment: what about skype?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Yes, I think real-time chat is important. I realize math.stackexchange.com actually *does* have chat (I think all stackexchange sites do), but the questions there are fairly high-level. I'm looking to help students struggling with math in high school and early college. I think it would be great if more students posted on math.stackexchange.com, but it's just not that popular of a site.

Comment: @celeriko SkyPE's a great platform, but I first need to find students that need help.

Comment: @BarryCarter ahhh ok i understand now, thank you for clarifying

Comment: Khan Academy is a place where high school students ask for help.  Not all the questions are worthwhile, but I can always find some worth answering.

Comment: @AmyB Thanks. I found https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/d (and similar community boards) after some digging, but couldn't find a link for "show me all questions asked in math". Also, this doesn't appear to be real-time. However, this is definitely a good resource, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for a place to teach virtually for quite a long time. I have finally found Cheery Education Center in Kibera, Nairobi, Kenya, that appreciated a little help in education (and still does). I found it through Skype in the classroom, there I searched for teachers who mystery Skype and looked at their profile.

Comment: Can give more details about practically reaching the students?

Comment: http://www.cheerycentre.org/ is the website. Write to info@cheerycentre.org and you can agree on the time and conditions of skype